# Detect whether EXE file is locked by running?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I need to sign an .exe file with ..\x64\signtool.exe. However, this obviously does not work while the .exe program is running which assumingly locks the .exe file. So I try to detect whether the .exe file is locked with this function:

```
function IsExeFileLocked(const AFilename: string): Boolean;
var
  F: TFileStream;
begin
  try
    F:=TFileStream.Create(AFilename, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    try
      Result:=False;
    finally
      F.Free;
    end;
  except
    Result:=True;
  end;
end;
```

But this function always gives back `False`, even if the .exe program is running!

So how can I detect whether an .exe file is locked by running?

Comment: You appear to be asking the wrong question. Since you attempt to sign an executable, just sign that executable. If it fails, implement appropriate recovery strategies. Singling out a single cause of failure doesn't look like a tractable solution. Introducing a TOCTTOU race isn't going to prove advantageous either.

Comment: you not need detect this. simply try do with file what you need todo. if file is locked - you got relevant error

Comment: So is there no way to detect whether exe file is locked by running?

Comment: Say for example the exe file is very large. In this case it takes a relatively long time before the signtool failes. Asking whether the exe file is locked by running would be much faster.

Comment: @user1580348 - but when you try do something with it (say open for write) and give error sharing violation - this is detect

Comment: Your code tries to open the executable for reading. Of course this succeeds even if the executable is running. The system doesn't deny reading.

Comment: You may enumerate all running processes to find out if your executable is running. See [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102407/enumerate-running-processes-in-delphi) to find out how to do this.

Comment: @WillyK. This does not work in all cases. I have even tried with GetModuleFileNameEx which in many cases works only if the app has elevated privileges. I have been behind this for a full day of intensive research. - I will follow the advice of IInspectable.

Comment: @WillyK. The EXE may also be locked for other reaons than running. E. g. an antivirus program scanning it.

Comment: *Say for example the exe file is very large. In this case it takes a relatively long time before the signtool failes.* - no. signtool fail just - when it try open file with write access. as result size of file not play role at all here

Comment: @RbMm You are right.

Comment: signtool.exe will return an error code to the caller when signing fails for any reason. Use this returned code to correctly handle the failure.