# How to determine the owner of a system process

Tags: delphi, winapi, process

The basics of this question are already discussed widely, but I have a specific difference:

My app knows the pid of a process and needs to determine the owner of this process. I implemented it like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1102503/2925238 using WinApi `OpenProcess`, `OpenProcessToken`, `GetTokenInformation` and `LookupAccountSid`.

My app is started with admin rights (via manifest, so UAC asks at start).

**The problem:**
The upper solution does not work for processes with owner SYSTEM. There OpenProcess() fails.

Does anyone know how accomplish this?

One thing that really confused me: if I start my app via IDE in debugging mode, somehow it works. (comparing the two instances with ProcessExplorer the only difference I could find was the set/unset SeDebugPriviledge)

I know there is the WMI solution, but this may be too slow.

For reference: Win10, Delphi 10.2, App is x64

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess "If the caller has enabled the SeDebugPrivilege privilege, the requested access is granted regardless of the contents of the security descriptor." "If the specified process is the System process or one of the Client Server Run-Time Subsystem (CSRSS) processes, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED because their access restrictions prevent user-level code from opening them."

Comment: PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION must be used

Comment: @RbMm I use PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION which already includes PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights

Comment: @casiosmu Yes, but you're asking for more than you need using `QUERY` instead of only `QUERY_LIMITED`. That's like asking a stranger for his name, age and education instead of just asking for directions. If you do the former, chances are the stranger also won't give you directions.

Comment: @AmigoJack it seems that they forgot to implement this constant in the Delphi WinApi file, so I tested it directly with the hex value (0x1000) from the MS doc. Unfortunately: nothing changed. OpenProcess is still refused for SYSTEM owned process

Comment: @casiosmu Depends on your Delphi version (which is why one should always refer to the WinAPI documentation instead of blindly expecting every constant to exist) and on your Windows version (Win XP doesn't support that flag) - none of both details have been addressed in your Q. Since you could develop for/in a VM running Win XP I'm not writing this fully in vain.

Comment: if you use `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` and have `SeDebugPrivilege` enabled you can open any process

Comment: @AmigoJack Thanks. I added the version information.

Comment: @RbMm Understand. But is it really recommended to use the `SeDebugPrivilege` in a release?

Comment: @casiosmu i dont understand your question.